# clause ending ようで clarification

Tags: grammar, auxiliaries

> でも生徒同士で序列をつける**ようで**、こうした風習もどうもね……
>
> 手はまったく届かなかったが願いは届いた**ようで**、謎の生命体は翼をはためかせてメアの頭に着地した
>
> あいつの意見が正しかったことだけは認めざるを得ない**ようで**、亮二もそれ以上食って掛かりはしなかった。
>
> 俺もノートに向かい続ける授業は苦手な**ようで**、自然に体を動かす実技授業が多くなった

I can't really come up with a concise interpretation of this usage. I read ようで as both a situation summarization and a cause indicator all in one, but it feels clumsy.

The 4th sentence, for example, has much more of a "because feeling" in it than the first one.  The 2nd and 3rd sentence feels like it's more in the middle in terms of cause.

(since) i'm not good with just looking at the board and taking notes, naturally i have more physically active practical  classes.

vs

But applying a hierarchy among the students,  that sort of custom...(stuck between a rock and hard place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ようで just the continuative form of ようだ, which expresses similarity to something else.  You can understand all your examples in this way.

> でも生徒同士で序列をつける**ようで**、こうした風習もどうもね……

But the students have made something which **appears to be** a ranking...

> 手はまったく届かなかったが願いは届いたようで、謎の生命体は翼をはためかせてメアの頭に着地した

Although my(?) hand was completely unable to reach them, my(?) wish **appeared to** have reached them...

> あいつの意見が正しかったことだけは認めざるを得ない**ようで**、亮二もそれ以上食って掛かりはしなかった。

It **appears** 亮二 has no choice but to acknowledge that あいつ's opinion was correct...

> 俺もノートに向かい続ける授業は苦手な**ようで**、自然に体を動かす実技授業が多くなった

I also **appear to be** bad with classes where you always look at your notes...

Comment: i've thought of that too, but with the 1st and 4th sentences, the speakers already have complete information for a long time. Regarding the school, the speaker is a long time student and those customs have been there since the school's inception, and the for the 4th sentence the speaker obviously know what kind of person they are. So "it seems/appears " doesn't feel like a one size fits all approach to me since it feels awkward imply uncertainty when there isn't any. It does fit better for the 2/3 sentence.

Comment: @charu Well, especially for the 4th sentence, I think that's the speaker being euphemistic about what hes good at (i.e. instead of saying he can't do it period, he says that he's doesn't seem to be very good at something.). The first example, I think the speaker either only recently learned the fact or is trying to distance himself from it. Similar to definition 3 from here: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/226613/meaning/m0u/